# how do i find a memory leak in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, memory-leak

I have a digital ocean droplet. recently i combined it with another, and now the system will randomly (every couple days) completely max out on CPU usage (for a single user, not for the system) and it throws a bunch of "out of memory" errors. i cant use top to figure out what process is causing the problem because it happens randomly.

to try to solve the problem, i recently quadrupled the available memory and CPU power. the problem went away for about a month and now it's happening again, more often than before.

i dont know when its going to strike. and when it does, it locks up the entire system and i have to hard reboot. i checked /var/log/messages and i see a bunch of "out of memory" errors from php, mysqld, spamd, and some other stuff. how do i figure out which user is causing the problem, and more specifically, how do i figure out how to solve it?

for context, it's a regular web hosting system that has cpanel installed.

Comment: Setup a tool that periodically stores the memory usage of all your processes?  Perhaps something as simple as a */5 cron that does something like `ps aux > "/path/ps_output_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)"`.  When it crashes, just look at what was happening 5 minutes before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the OOM messages. It will print out memory usage details at the time and the PID that was killed. That task is not necessarily the root cause, it just looked big to the kernel at the time.

Look at /proc/meminfo and watch processes with top. You should know approximately how much memory the system is sized for. Say a 4 GB instance intends 2 GB for DB shared memory, 1 GB for web server processes, and 1 GB for OS and admin tools. Any one of these categories exceeding their estimate would cause memory pressure.

Measure memory use per service precisely with cgroup accounting. Containers do this, although you have not said you are using containers.

systemd slices also use cgroups, if that is your service manager. Set  [DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html) and review the output of systemd-cgtop. Try cgroup aware monitoring over time with tools like [netdata's cgroups plugin](https://docs.netdata.cloud/collectors/cgroups.plugin/).  Set resource limits on the unit once you know what they should be.